# Copy formatted date from excel to notepad

Tags: mysql, excel, date

I have extracted some data from mysql table a to excel. Now I have to create insert queries to insert into table b. In the table it has more than million records. Now in excel file, dates are converted into number. I have formatted the number to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss as required by mysql. But in insert query it remain number. Check the image as well. 
image link:
http://s8.postimg.org/6g8fvf851/Capture.png

please tell me how can i copy the formatted date into notepad or sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you should use `text` function to convert excel date to string.

```
=text(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

You can use this expression in your `concatenate` function or convert the dates to string representation, then use them in your formula.

Excel uses number to represent date. `0` means `1900-01-00` which is not exists. `1` means `1900-01-01`. `1/24` means 1 hour, `1/24/60` means 1 minute and `1/24/60/60` means 1 second. You can check it by entering expression `=1+1/24+1/24/60+1/24/60/60` in a cell then change its format to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. It will show `1900-01-01 01:01:01`.